# Where does the excess positive charge in a conductor reside?

Tags: electrostatics

I have read the other questions on the site and my book uses Gauss' Law to prove that the charge would remain on the surface. While for a negative charges I do agree (electrons) that they will remain on the surface due to inter electronic repulsion, I don't understand why for positive charges the whole conductor wont have an uniform positive charge density. I am looking for a physical description of the inner working of the conductor without any mathematics (perhaps along the lines of chemical bonding itself). 
My question succinctly would be why not a positive charge density throughout the conductor and not only on the surface?

Comment: Any extra charge given to a conductor, positive or negative, resides on its surface which follows from the fact that the average electric field is zero inside a conductor.

Comment: Free electrons will be everywhere, except for the surface.

Comment: I am looking for an answer based on why the free electrons wont spread out to the surface and the charge density throughtout the whole conductor?

Comment: @Arya If the electrons move out to the surface, the electric field inside the bulk of the metal will be nonzero (due to the unneutralized positive charges of the nuclei). But the electric field cannot be nonzero inside a metal. If you put some additional charges, positive or negative, to a previously neutral chunk of metal, those charges will reside on the surface.

Answer (score 1):

Positive charges on the surface create a zero electric field inside and therefore do not attract free electrons. However, positive charges inside the conductor will attract free electrons away from the surface.

Answer (score 1):

In the classical framework, inside the conductor there is zero field. The mathematics is rigorous and the experimental effects validate it.

In the [microscopic view](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/miccur.html) of how currents are built up by electrons and positive ions or positive "holes" there exist charges throughout because the conductor is composed of *neutral*  atoms and molecules.

[image: microcurrent]

The classical behavior emerges because an electron leaving a neutral atom leaves a positive hole behind which is filled up by the next electron drifting in the current direction , so overall the volume remains neutral.

In a hand waving way one can intuit that because of the discontinuity at the surface, of a charged conducting sphere as an example, the charge cannot be neutralized and excess negative can be deposited in energy levels of the [band structure](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Solids/band.html) of the conductor,or electrons removed from the band leaving the surface positive.

> I don't understand why for positive charges the whole conductor wont have an uniform positive charge density.

If all the atoms and molecules would lose an electron, the lattice structure would be destroyed. The solid state lattice depends on the [orbitals of the outer electrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molecular_orbital) which generate a LEGO like structure, (again hand waving) with positive and negative electric fields around each atom/molecule so that they are attracted and bind into a lattice. It is only the conduction band of electrons which belong to the whole lattice, and removing one electron from the band creates a positive hole. Asymmetry happens only at the conductor surface, so there negative electrons and positive holes could reside.